# Google map, программно выйти из полноэкранного режима

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Задача заключается в выходе с полноэкранного режима, программно.
Никак не могу понять, что нужно использовать?
Надо, чтобы по нажатию кнопки перехода (не косающую карты), карта выходила из полноэкранного режима, но нужно знать, что она действительно в полноэкранном режиме.
Иначе - это будет последующим входом в полноэкранный режим.
Может как-то через `fullscreenControl` можно сделать?
Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fullscreenControl - это просто свойство google.maps.Map, которое добавляет контрол к карте.

Надо смотреть в сторону Fullscreen API, в котором есть, например, свойство [fullscreenElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenElement) и метод [exitFullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/exitFullscreen)